# Unique SQL , depending on another field

Tags: sql

I have a table of clients, and each client has a table of sections with the following columns:

ID

name

ClientID

Is it possible to make the name unique, based on the clientID?
For example, every client could have a section with the name Office but only one per client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create so then use this query

```
CREATE TABLE clients 
(
ID int NOT NULL,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
ClientID int
CONSTRAINT Cli_Con UNIQUE (ClientID, name)
)
```

If you want to alter then use this query

```
ALTER TABLE clients ADD CONSTRAINT Cli_Con  UNIQUE (ClientID, name);
```

Comment: How do i relate the Clients table with the Sections table, so that unique row in the sections is only unique to each client?
that script appears to only affect the clients table.

Comment: Ya it's affect only Client table. Can you state your problem clearly

Comment: Ill try to improve my explaination:
I Have 2 tables
Clients and Sections
The Section table have all the sections of all clients.
So we have something like:


ID     Name       Client_ID

1      office     13

2      office     13

3      office     14


what i want is that client with id 13 can only have on section with the name office, same for all clients.
so it would mean there would be several sections with same name, but  each client would only have one section with that name.

Comment: Yes the above query will help you for this case.Since your ClientID is related to another table

Comment: on your script above, is it really CREATE TABLE clients , or CREATE TABLE Sections?

Comment: May i know how u did?

Comment: i used the alter line that you and Lee provided, but replaced clients with Sections

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique multi-column index.

```
alter table clients add unique index(ClientID, name);
```